# How to use double $ in echo

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
[sudhir.tataraju.WBLL0717E4418] ➤ cat test.sh

#!bin/bash

i=2

value2=abc

echo "`$value$i`"
```

Output:

```
[sudhir.tataraju.WBLL0717E4418] ➤ sh test.sh
test.sh: line 8: 2: command not found
```

Debug output:

```
[sudhir.tataraju.WBLL0717E4418] ➤ sh -x test.sh
+ i=2
+ value2=abc
++ 2
test.sh: line 8: 2: command not found
+ echo ''
```

How to get output **abc** without error?

Comment: `eval echo "\$value$i"`

Comment: A couple of asides: is `#!bin/bash` the first line in your file or the second? Also, you should have `#!/bin/bash` for the absolute path.

Comment: Seems to me that you are just looking for the functionality of arrays, for example: `i=2; arr=(abc def ghi); echo "${arr[i]}"`.

Comment: `sh -x test.sh` is not running `test.sh` with bash, it's running it as a POSIX sh script. Use `bash -x test.sh` (and consider [leaving the `.sh` extension off entirely](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), as implying that a bash script can be run with `/bin/sh` is actively misleading, and using extensions for command names is contrary to UNIX convention -- you don't run `ls.elf`).

Comment: (...so, to be clear, when you use `sh` manually, you're causing the `#!/bin/bash` shebang to be ignored).

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying to do can be achieved much better with arrays.

```
values=( value1 value2 value3 "This is value 4" )
echo "${values[2]}"
values[2]="other_value"
echo "${values[2]}"
```

Variables can also be used as the index:

```
i=2
echo "${values[$i]}"
```

---

Arrays make looping over the values very easy:

```
#looping over values
for value in "${values[@]}"; do
    echo "$value"
done
#looping over indexes
for index in "${!values[@]}"; do
    echo "${values[$index]}"
done
```

If you don't consider sparse or associative arrays, you can also loop like this:

```
for (( index=0; index<${#values[@]}; index++ )); do
    echo "${values[index]}"
done
```

---

Arrays are the right structure for your task. They offer great functionality. For more information on arrays, see: [wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays) and [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html).

Comment: I'm split -- on one hand, it's a good answer; on the other hand, it's an answer to a FAQ we see re-asked at least monthly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True. This answer is pretty frequent. However, so is the question and other answers. I am still relatively new here so if you think deletion of this answer/some editing is appropriate, please tell me so :)

Comment: Heh. In hindsight, it probably would have been appropriate for the regulars -- the folks who knew better -- to jump on the close vote more quickly. Now that there are bad answers present, though, withdrawing the good ones would do more harm than good.

Answer (score 5):

What you're asking for can be achieved in two ways (without antipatterns or `eval`).

1. Use [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

   > The basic form of parameter expansion is `${parameter}`. The value of parameter is substituted. [...] **If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!),** [...] it introduces a level of variable indirection. **Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable;** this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself. This is known as *indirect expansion.*

   So what you want is:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   i=2

   value2=abc

   # Have a variable that expands to the name of the variable you want
   myvar=value$i

   # Use indirect expansion
   echo "${!myvar}"
   ```
2. Realize that your design is very bad, and use some proper structure instead: Bash handles arrays. See [PesaThe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48042786/1815797). That's definitely the recommended method in your case.

---

Don't use `eval`. Though it might look great, you need a good deal of practice of shell scripting before you understand all the problems with `eval`. And when you have enough experience with Bash, you'll realize that you very very rarely need `eval`.

Comment: I'm split -- on one hand, it's a good answer; on the other hand, it's an answer to a FAQ we see re-asked at least monthly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval`:

```
eval echo "\$value$i"
```

From `help eval`:

> ```
> eval: eval [arg ...]  
>    Execute arguments as a shell command.
>
>    Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell,  
>    and execute the resulting commands.
> ```

So the command is first expanded to

```
eval echo "$value2"
```

Note the first dollar is escaped so it isn't expanded as `$value`

Then `eval` takes effect: The whole command is evaluated again:

```
echo "abc"
```

Output, as desired: `abc`

Comment: `eval` should not be suggested to non-experts (except in very very specific cases, and this isn't one).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Fine.

Comment: To clarify the "why" of that -- using `eval` creates [substantial security concerns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), and with bash having built-in indirect expansion mechanisms, it's [completely unnecessary](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using *[nameref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters)*:

```
i=2
value2="abc"
declare -n essai=value"$i"
echo "$essai"
```

Comment: Worth mentioning this requires `bash` 4.3 or later.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a complete example that works

```
#!/bin/bash

val1='foo'
val2='bar' 
val3='baz'

for i in {1..3}
do
  eval echo "\$val${i}"
done
```

Comment: How to get output `abc`?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [iBug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48042115/6176817) to me. Also, you can use `{1..3}` or at least use `$(cmd)`.

Comment: seq 1 3 {1..3} is the exact same thing, just semantics. And since the person asking the question seems pretty new to bash, I think seq 1 3 is a little clearer what it does.

Comment: @opentokix it is not the same thing at all! Using `seq` creates a new process, it is an external tool, whereas brace expansion is done directly by `bash`.

Comment: @PesaThe I am sorry your toaster ran out of resources.

Comment: // , @PesaThe what do you mean by `seq`? I don't see that in this answer

Comment: @NathanBasanese well, because the answer was edited after my comment.